# Client Certificate does not work on .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, httpclient, .net-6.0, client-certificates

**EDIT2: It also works with .NET 7.0, straight on my mac machine... I can't upgrade to 7.0 though, so I am still stuck...**

**EDIT: Running the exact same code on a docker container with .NET 6 also works... Could this problem only happens on MacOS ?**

I am facing a weird issue in which I am trying to make an https call with a client certificate authentication and I am getting a "400 The SSL certificate error" response from the server.

The weirdness is that running the EXACT same code with .NET Core 3.1 simply works...

Has anyone seen anything like that?

I wrote a simplified version of my code, but it reproduces the problem perfectly:

```cs
const string url = "https://myservice";
const string path = "myendpoint";
var fileData = File.ReadAllBytes("/some/certificate.p12");
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(fileData, "the_cert_password");
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual
};
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler)
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(url)
};

var httpMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Content = new StringContent("{}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    RequestUri = new Uri($"{httpClient.BaseAddress}{path}")
};
var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpMessage);
var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Console.WriteLine(content);
```

Comment: Try connecting to the server with the `curl` tool, which can show a detailed dump of TLS tunnel establishment and show you a more detailed error message. Alternatively, `openssl` can be used to debug TLS as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? I am not used to curl beyond very basic calls

Comment: What's the exact, *full* error message? And what is the server? Is it a .NET 6 service perhaps? It's possible the server no longer trusts the self-signed certificate.

Comment: The error is very generic, I believe
```<html>
<head><title>400 The SSL certificate error</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The SSL certificate error</center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The server is a .NET Core 3.1 API

Comment: If it was a server trust problem I'd see the same problem running from .NET 3.1 or from the docker container, wouldn't I ?